# R read.table with UTF-8 encoded file reads infinity symbol as 8 (int)

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm reading in a UTF-8 encoded data file using read.table. When using the 'encoding="UTF-8"' option, any infinity symbols are read as the number 8.

For what its worth, this is the offending line:

```
read.table(file.path(workingDir, "datafile.csv"), sep=",", blank.lines.skip=TRUE, allowEscapes=FALSE, header=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
```

A snippet of the file:

[image]

All other values are read correctly so I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: If you type `∞` into the R console, the only way it interprets it is as `8`. R understands `\U221E` as that symbol, but you might have to swap `∞`  with `\U221E` (or `Inf` which R understands) before you import. Not sure if there is another way to handle this. If you want R to understand `∞` as infinity in the mathematical sense, you want to end up with values stored as `Inf/-Inf`

Comment: Thanks Mako. I had noticed this when testing in R Studio; I think that almost constitutes a bug? Problem I have is that this is part of an application that allows users to select input files. Those input files are created with Inf but some editors seem to change it to the symbol and so it circumvents the original file creation. I am really trying to avoid re-converting back to Inf as these files can be quite large (10s of GBs). Do you know of an elegant way in R to handle this conversion on import?

Comment: An update, if I save an Excel file with `∞`, and then read it in with `readxl::read_excel`, it correctly displays the symbol. However, if I `dput` the object, it converts to character `8`s

Comment: Unfortunately, `str` and `class` don't tell me anything that explains why it's correctly displaying the symbol.

Comment: I think it will require some deep dive into how readxl is written but it gives a small hint potentially; dput makes some sense in that it converts to ASCII so will lose the infinity symbol. Perhaps, underneath the hood, even with the encoding option, r is storing the read.table values as ascii

Comment: It's strange though, because something like `read.table(text = "ж")` returns `<U+0436>`, but it seems as though for `∞` for whatever reason, R doesn't recognize it as a unicode character.

Comment: How are you testing? I can reproduce what you say in R Studio but when I use either CMD or CMDER, it all goes wrong: both support the characters without the R session running but as soon as I launch `r --vanilla`, neither infinity nor Zhe symbol can even be pasted to the shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187891/discussion-between-mako212-and-daveb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an encoding bug in R on Windows, as you already reported on [r-devel](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Bug-Report-read-table-with-UTF-8-encoded-file-imports-infinity-symbol-as-Integer-8-td4755296.html).

You can do the following as a workaround:

Read your data with {readr} (due to the bug, you cannot use the literal infinity symbol in R, but have to use the unicode escape `\u221E` instead).

```r
library(readr)
(xdf <- read_csv("x, y\n\u221E, 2", col_types = cols(.default = col_character())))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 ∞     2
```

Here we read in all columns as character (and not numeric), because we have to replace the infinity symbol to `Inf` later. See `help(readr::cols())` for details on how to specify the column type.

Now replace the infinity symbol with the reserved word for infinity in R, `Inf` and convert to numeric. I am using `str_replace()` from {stringr} here, but this ought to work with `base::gsub()` as well.

```r
library(stringr) 
as.numeric(str_replace(xdf$x, pattern= "\u221E", replacement = "Inf"))
#> [1] Inf
```

If you want to do this to all columns in your data.frame, you can do this with `mutate_all` function from `dplyr` for example.

```r
library(dplyr)
mutate_all(xdf, str_replace, pattern= "\u221E", replacement = "Inf") %>% 
  mutate_all(as.numeric)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   Inf     2
```